# output unique year set from datetime index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a datetime index as below,

```
>>> temp
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06',
               '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-12',
               '2017-01-13', '2017-01-16',
               ...
               '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29', '2018-01-02',
               '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-08',
               '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=251, freq=None)
>>> temp.year
Int64Index([2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017,
            ...
            2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
           dtype='int64', length=251)
```

I want to output unique year, for example as a list [2017,2018].
I have tried below command but it is not working as I expected.

```
>>> temp.year.drop_duplicates
<bound method Index.drop_duplicates of Int64Index([2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017,
 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017,
            ...
            2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
           dtype='int64', length=251)>
```

any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss `()`, also is necessary convert to list:

```
L = temp.year.drop_duplicates().tolist()

L = list(temp.year.drop_duplicates())
```

Another solution with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
L = list(temp.year.unique())

print (L)
[2017, 2018]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to this:

```
df.index.year.unique().values
```

returns:

> [2017 2018]

or, for a list:

```
df.index.year.unique().to_list()
```

returns:

> [2017, 2018]